# How to Split a Paragraph into Sentences

Tags: php, regex, split, text-segmentation

I've been trying to use:

```
$string="The Dr. is here!!! I am glad I'm in the U.S.A. for the Dr. quality is great!!!!!!";
preg_match_all('~.*?[?.!]~s',$string,$sentences);
print_r($sentences);
```

But it doesn't work on Dr., U.S.A., etc.

Does anyone have any better suggestions?

Comment: I don't know regex well enough, but I was thinking if there's a way to say the sentence before the last has to be at least 5 character long or something like that...

Comment: Something like this:
(\w+'?\s?)+\.

Comment: Well, to meet the case provided you'll want a regex that checks for a space followed by an uppercase letter, before it does the split. I'm not familiar with Regex's, probably you could do this though, but I think the rules may soon get more complicated, and probably you'd use a combination of a simple regex + a little state machine to do it properly.

Comment: The space followed by an uppercase letter won't necessarily work. Imagine working with this sentence: `Hello, Dr. Smith is ready for you. Please go to the E.R. where he is waiting.`

Comment: Aaron: That's why I said you'd need to combine it with a state machine.

Comment: @Aaron and silky -  What's a state machine?  Sorry, I've not been formally trained, and might know what it is, but not what its called.  I've looked on wiki, didn't really help...

Comment: Scott: It's really just an area where you decide on the course of action based on the current 'state' of some variables. So you'll be at the '.' and you'll have a 'previousWord' of 'Dr'. You can then look that up in a list of, say, "Legal words ending in . but not ending a sentence" (or some further-complicated model) and decide whether to break into a sentence at that point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032210/php-sentence-boundaries-detection

Answer (score 11):

there is not any simple solution for that. you need do some natural language processing(NLP) in your application and recognize each sentence. there is something call [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/), it's a JAVA-based NLP parser tool. Or [Stanford NLP parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) in Ruby. you can find something like that for php.

[here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nlp/) I found a set of classes for natural language processing in PHP.

Comment: +1 - and indeed, even a solution that uses NLP is likely to fail when faced with sufficiently informal (e.g. sloppy) writing,  If people don't follow the basic rules of punctuation, you are stuffed.

Comment: Seems like the files for that project are no longer online

Answer (score 1):

hmmm maybe try something like `$sentences = preg_split('/.*?[?.!]+\s+/', $string);`

Answer (score 0):

This is almost impossible since your example clearly indicates that punctuation characters that can be used in e.g. Dr., U.S.A etc, make it impossible to know where a sentence starts/ends.

You have to search the following characters to decide if a new sentence follows (starts after) the punctuation chars you are mentioning.