# Regular expression for counting sentences in a block of text

Tags: php, regex, nlp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - How to split a paragraph into sentences.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158296/php-how-to-split-a-paragraph-into-sentences)

I have a block of text that I would like to separate into sentences, what would be the best way of doing this? I thought of looking for '.','!','?' characters, but I realized there were some problems with this, such as when people use acronyms, or end a sentence with something like !?.  What would be the best way to handle this? I figured there would be some regex that could handle this, but I'm open to a non-regex solution if that fits the problem better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex isn't the best solution for this problem.  You'd be served better by creating a parsing library.  Something where you an easily create logic blocks to distinguish one thing from another.  You'll need to come up with a set of rules breaking up the text into the chunks you'd like to see.

```
"Are you sure?" he asked.
```

Doesn't that mess things up when using regex?  However, with a parser you could actually see

```
<start quote><capitalization>are you sure<question><end quote>he asked<period>
```

that with simple rules could say "that's one sentence."

Comment: Or, annoyingly, you could get things like `"Are you sure"? he asked.` which are semantically correct but look oh so wrong. Also, nouns which contain punctuation are also bad: `Which? recommend buying....`

Comment: Actually the ? should be inside the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no perfect solution for this, for the very reasons you stated.  If it is content that you can somehow control or force a specified delimiter after every sentence, that would be ideal.  Beyond that, all you can really do is look for `(\.|!|?)+`  and maybe even throw in a \s after that since most people pad new sentences with 1 or 2 spaces between the previous and next sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest problem is the possible existence of acronyms! Therefore you must use something like `Prof.&nbsp;Knuth` in a JavaDoc summary sentence so that the javadoc generator don't thinks that the first sentence ends after `Prof.`.
This is a problem I don't know how anyone can  reliably handle. The only approximate solution I could imagine is the use of an abbreviation dictionary.

Comment: There are no acronyms (words formed out of the initials of other words, i.e. ASAP) in your example, only an abbreviation (a word represented by a leading subset of the usual letters).