# Regular expression match a sentence

Tags: java, regex

How can I match a sentence of the form "Hello world" or "Hello World". The sentence may contain "- / digit 0-9". Any information will be very helpful to me. Thank you.

Comment: How is the first one (`"Hello world"`) a sentence? There's no punctuation.

Comment: @baba You're right haha. I fixed it.

Comment: You wrote: `may contain "- / digit 0-9"`? No letters allowed? The question is confusing...

Comment: @Matt Ball It's a fair bet this isn't a natural language question, and a 'sentence' in regular expression theory is any sequence of input characters which belongs to the 'language' accepted by the regular expression.

Comment: Actually, I found this to be a pretty challenging question! (See  the test data from my answer.) Matching a last sentence having no punctuation makes it a bit trickier.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This one will do a pretty good job. My definition of a sentence: A sentence begins with a non-whitespace and ends with a period, exclamation point or a question mark (or end of string). There may be a closing quote following the ending punctuation.

`[^.!?\s][^.!?]*(?:[.!?](?!['"]?\s|$)[^.!?]*)*[.!?]?['"]?(?=\s|$)`

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String subjectString = 
        "This is a sentence. " +
        "So is \"this\"! And is \"this?\" " +
        "This is 'stackoverflow.com!' " +
        "Hello World";
        String[] sentences = null;
        Pattern re = Pattern.compile(
            "# Match a sentence ending in punctuation or EOS.\n" +
            "[^.!?\\s]    # First char is non-punct, non-ws\n" +
            "[^.!?]*      # Greedily consume up to punctuation.\n" +
            "(?:          # Group for unrolling the loop.\n" +
            "  [.!?]      # (special) inner punctuation ok if\n" +
            "  (?!['\"]?\\s|$)  # not followed by ws or EOS.\n" +
            "  [^.!?]*    # Greedily consume up to punctuation.\n" +
            ")*           # Zero or more (special normal*)\n" +
            "[.!?]?       # Optional ending punctuation.\n" +
            "['\"]?       # Optional closing quote.\n" +
            "(?=\\s|$)", 
            Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
        Matcher reMatcher = re.matcher(subjectString);
        while (reMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(reMatcher.group());
        } 
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

`This is a sentence.`
`So is "this"!`
`And is "this?"`
`This is 'stackoverflow.com!'`
`Hello World`

Matching all of these correctly (with the last sentence having no ending punctuation), turns out to be not so easy as it seems!

Comment: Shouldn't a sentence start with a capital letter, if it is starting with a letter? 1 of 100 examples starts with a uppercase letter, but with no letter at all.

Comment: @user unknown: Maybe. But a sentence can be whatever you want to define it to be. My definition is stated above. For example, a sentence may begin with the name of program variable which starts with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thank you. Actually my question was incomplete as I wrote it in hurry. I should state what I meant by a sentence. Your help is really appreciable. Thanks again.

Comment: `x` should be quoted at the beginning of the sentence. :)

Comment: @Tapas Bose: You can easily change the part of the regex which matches the first char. If you need it to start with a capital letter, change the `[^.!?\\s]` to just `[A-Z]`. Glad to be of help!

Comment: @ridgerunner, can you plz give another RE which can exclude incomplete sentence ie "Hello World" in this case. And can include initials as a part of sentence. Currently, any initial (like Prof. or Mr. ) appears as different sentence and break a complete sentences into multiple sentences.

Comment: @articlestack  Take a look at my answer to another similar question: [php sentence boundaries detection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5844564/433790). That one handles; mr., mrs., dr., etc.

Comment: @ridgerunner, I have already have seen it. but it giving me error. Although I have done in old style but was looking some smart way as you answered.

Comment: How would you modify this so that you could only capture a sentence that contains a given word within it?  ie, just grab sentences that have "Hello"

Comment: @Patrick - If even possible, the resulting regex would be extremely complex. The obvious way to handle this would to first parse the sentences, then look inside each sentence one at a time for the given word.

Answer (score 0):

If by sentence you mean something that ends with a punctuation mark try this : `(.*?)[.?!]`

Explanation :

- `.*` matches any string. Adding a `?` makes it non-greedy matching (matches the smallest string possible)
- `[.?!]` matches any of the three punctuation marks

Comment: That won't work on this input: `"Why am I Mr. Pink?"`

Comment: Ok you got me there. Now you might need a list of "irregularities" such as this one and put them aside. Anyway, the question is closed now.