# Parsing text, but keeping punctuation

Tags: ios, parsing, nsstring, nscharacterset

I'm using this little piece of code to go through some inputted text and extracting sentences separated by the markers:

```
NSCharacterSet *punctuation =
[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@".!?\n"];
NSArray *parts = [data componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:punctuation];
```

The issue is that the resulting array is stripped from the punctuation. How do i go about storing the data with the appropriate punctuation? If possible, i'd like keep sentences marked with a newline (\n) as they are.

For example, if I enter this:

> This is a sentence. It is marked by a period. This sentence is not marked by one How do you do? I'm doing very good!

I'd like to get something like this:

> This is a sentence.
>   It is marked by a period.
>   This sentence is not marked by one
>   How do you do?
>   I'm doing very good!

Comment: This works in Java, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553410/regular-expression-match-a-sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
NSString *string = @"This is a sentence. It is marked by a period. This sentence is not marked by one How do you do? I'm doing very good!";
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *pattern = @"(\\.|,|!|\\?|\\n)\\s*";
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                            options:0
                                                                              error:&error];
if (expression)
{
    NSArray *matches = [expression matchesInString:string
                                           options:0
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    NSLog(@"%@", matches);
    if ([matches count] > 0)
    {
        NSMutableArray *sentences = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[matches count]];
        NSUInteger sentenceStart = 0;
        for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in matches)
        {
            NSUInteger sentenceEnd = result.range.location + 1;
            [sentences addObject:[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(sentenceStart, sentenceEnd - sentenceStart)]];
            sentenceStart = sentenceEnd + (result.range.length - 1);
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", sentences);
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[NSString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString: ByString:]` instead.

e.g `[NSString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"." ByString:@".\n"];`

and similar for other symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Yogi's answer will do for inserting newlines. However, if you want to put the string parts in an array, you can use this workaround:

```
data = [data stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@".&§"];
data = [data stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"!" withString:@"!&§"];
data = [data stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@"?&§"];
NSArray *parts = [data componentsSeparatedByString:@"&§"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *yourString = @"This is a sentence. It is marked by a period. This sentence is not marked by one How do you do? I'm doing very good!";
    NSMutableCharacterSet *punctuation = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@".!?\n"];
   [punctuation formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]];
    NSMutableArray *words = [[yourString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:punctuation] mutableCopy];
```

Hope this will help you......

Comment: This doesn't accomplish what i'm trying to do.