# How do I append a list of negative lookbehinds to a python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split a paragraph into sentences using regex split and I'm trying to use the second answer posted here:
[a Regex for extracting sentence from a paragraph in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465335/a-regex-for-extracting-sentence-from-a-paragraph-in-python)

But I have a list of abbreviations that I don't want to end the sentence on even though there's a period. But I don't know how to append it to that regular expression properly. I'm reading in the abbreviations from a file that contains terms like Mr. Ms. Dr. St. (one on each line).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't, unless all lookbehind assertions are of the same, fixed width (which they probably aren't in your case; your example contained only two-letter abbreviations, but `Mrs.` would break your regex).

This is a limitation of the current Python regex engine.

Longer answer:

You *could* write a regex like `(?s)(?<!.Mr|Mrs|.Ms|.St)\.`, padding each alternating part of the lookbehind assertion with as many `.`s as needed to get all of them to the same width. However, that would fail in some circumstances, for example when a paragraph begins with `Mr.`.

Anyway, you're not using the right tool here. Better use a tool designed for the job, for example the [Natural Language Toolkit](http://nltk.org/).

If you're stuck with regex (too bad!), then you could try and use a `findall()` approach instead of `split()`:

```
(?:(?:\b(?:Mr|Ms|Dr|Mrs|St)\.)|[^.])+\.\s*
```

would match a sentence that ends in `.` (optionally followed by whitespace) and may contain no dots unless preceded by one of the allowed abbreviations.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "My name is Mr. T. I pity the fool who's not on the A-Team."
>>> re.findall(r"(?:(?:\b(?:Mr|Ms|Dr|Mrs|St)\.)|[^.])+\.\s*", s)
['My name is Mr. T. ', "I pity the fool who's not on the A-Team."]
```

Comment: I can only use the python stdlib. Is there any other way to take the abbreviations into consideration without using lookbehinds then?

Comment: *“This is a limitation of the current Python regex engine.”* – Do you have something for me to read about this limitation?

Comment: @poke: The [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) read: "`(?<=...)`: Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by a match for ... that ends at the current position. This is called a positive lookbehind assertion. `(?<=abc)def` will find a match in `abcdef`, since the lookbehind will back up 3 characters and check if the contained pattern matches. The contained pattern must only match strings of some fixed length, meaning that `abc` or `a|b` are allowed, but `a*` and `a{3,4}` are not. "

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Look-behind for a list of fixed text can be done (to some extent, with certain limitations).

Answer (score 1):

**I don't directly answer your question, but this post should contain enough information for you to write a working regex for your problem.**

You **can** append a list of negative look-behinds. Remember that look-behinds are zero-width, which means that you can put as many look-behinds as you want next to each other, and you are still look-behind from the same position. As long as you don't need to use "many" quantifier (e.g. `*`, `+`, `{n,}`) in the look-behind, everything should be fine (?).

So the regex can be constructured like this:

```
(?<!list )(?<!of )(?<!words )(?<!not )(?<!allowed )(?<!to )(?<!precede )pattern\w+
```

It is a bit too verbose. Anyway, I write this post just to demonstrate that it is possible to look-behind on a list of fixed string.

Example run:

```
>>> s = 'something patterning of patterned crap patternon not patterner, not allowed patternes to patternsses, patternet'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!list )(?<!of )(?<!words )(?<!not )(?<!allowed )(?<!to )(?<!precede )pattern\w+', s)
['patterning', 'patternon', 'patternet']
```

There is a catch in using look-behind, though. If there are dynamic number of spaces between the blacklisted text and the text matching the pattern, the regex above will fail. I really doubt there exists a way to modify the regex so that it works for the case above *while keeping the look-behinds*. (You can always replace consecutive spaces into 1, but it won't work for more general cases).

Comment: I have formatted my long list of literal text into a one long string like this:
(?<!Ala\. )(?<!Ariz\. )(?<!Assn\. )(?<!Atty\. )(?<!Aug\. )(?<!Ave\. )(?<!Bldg\. )(?<!Blvd\. )(?<!Calif\. )(?<!Capt\. )(?<!Cf\. )(?<!Ch\. )(?<!Co\. )(?<!Col\. )(?<!Colo\. )(?<!Conn\. )(?<!Corp\. )(?<!DR\. )(?<!Dec\. )(?<!Dept\. )(?<!Dist\. )(?<!Dr\. )(?<!Drs\. )(?<!Ed\. )(?<!Eq\. )(?<!FEB\. )(?<!Feb\. )(?<!Fig\. )(?<!Figs\. )(?<!Fla\. )(?<!Ga\. )(?<!Gen\. )(?<!Gov\. )(?<!HON\. )(?<!Ill\. )(?<!Inc\. )(?<!JR\. )(?<!Jan\. )(?<!Jr\. )(?<!Kan\. )(?<!Ky\. )(?<!La\. )(?<!Lt\. )(?<!Ltd\. )(?<!MR\. )
Would it work?

Comment: @user2017502: Look at the catch when using this. It is going to fail for the case `Mr.__X` (`_` is space - 2 spaces between `.` and name)