# I'm trying to split a sentence with Regex

Tags: php, regex

I've been trying to figure this out all day but how can I reliable split the next line in following order.

> Passive: Marks enemies who are isolated from nearby allies. Active:
>   Deals 70/100/130/160/190 (+) physical damage. If the target is
>   isolated, the amount is increased to 100/145/190/235/280 (+). Evolved
>   Enlarged Claws: Increases damage to isolated enemies by
>   12/12/12/12/12% of their missing health (max 200/200/200/200/200 vs.
>   monsters). Increases the range of Taste Their Fear and Kha'Zix's basic
>   attacks by 50/50/50/50/50.

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  Array
        (
            [0] => Passive
            [1] => Marks enemies who are isolated from nearby allies.
        )
    [1] =>  Array
        (
            [0] => Active
            [1] => Deals 70/100/130/160/190 (+) physical damage. If the target is isolated, the amount is increased to 100/145/190/235/280 (+).
        )
    [2] =>  Array
        (
            [0] => Evolved Enlarged Claws   
            [1] => Increases damage to isolated enemies by 12/12/12/12/12% of their missing health (max 200/200/200/200/200 vs. monsters). Increases the range of Taste Their Fear and Kha'Zix's basic attacks by 50/50/50/50/50.
        )
)
```

I can't get past the mid sentence periods.

Comment: You're better off looking for the keywords that have a colon at the end ("Active:", "Passive:" and "Evolved Enlarged Claws:") and using those. I can't see any way of splitting this up using periods.

Comment: It'll be matching `Passive`, `Active`.. in that order?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032210/php-sentence-boundaries-detection

Comment: Well where is your regex then? You want us to correct something you don't show...

Comment: @andrewsi Sorry let me clarify I didn't want to split up on the periods. I was trying to split it up on the colon and select the first part by going back to the previous period. But I can't figure out how to express this in regex.

Comment: You might want to add your regex to the question, in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?:^|\s*)([^.:]+):\s*(.+?\.)(?=[\w\s]+:|$)
```

Name is in capture group 1, description is in capture group 2

Comment: Thank you so much, this does exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this seems to do the trick...

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=^|[.] )([^:]+): (.+?[.])(?=[^.]+:|$)/', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($matches);
```

... if I understood the structure given (`'Term: Description. Term: Description'`, etc). It's actually colons within Description that might break it; dots do just fine here.

The result of this match can be quite easily transformed into an associative array:

```
$spell = array();
foreach ($matches as $match) {
   $spell[$match[1]] = $match[2];
}
```

Comment: This still seemed to error on the last part of the line. Patrick's solution however did work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.` as delimiter for parent/main array and `:` for sub arrays.

```
function so12625378_explode_to_multiarray( $string )
{
    foreach ( explode( ". ", $your_string ) as $part )
        $result[] = explode( ": ", $part );

    return $result;
}
```

Use:

```
 $string = 'Passive: Marks enemies who are isolated from nearby allies. Active: Deals 70/100/130/160/190 (+) physical damage. If the target is isolated, the amount is increased to 100/145/190/235/280 (+).';
 echo '<pre>'.var_export( so12625378_explode_to_multiarray( $string ), true ).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Did you check it? Apart from mistake (no argument passed to function, it should be written as `function someName ($your_string)`, perhaps), it breaks the same way as the OP mentioned.

Comment: @raina77ow No, I didn't - currently ain't in range of my dev env. Fixed. Thanks.