# How can I insert a <hr> after the first <p> or <br> following every 5,000 characters of some text?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, insert, word-count

I have some very long passages. I want to break them up for easier reading. I want to divide them by adding a `<hr>` tag for every 5,000 characters. But I also don't want to divide the text in the middle of a paragraph. So I want to add the `<hr>` tag just after the first `<p> or <br>` of every 5,000 characters. The 'text' has HTML formatting already so we can find the `<p> or <br>` directly within the text.

I can do it with PHP in the back end or JS/jQuery in the front-end, whichever is the better way.

I'm a novice and I'm completely stuck. I don't know how to achieve this. Hope you can help. Thank you very much!

Comment: What does the "text" look like?  Does it already have HTML formatting in it or is it simply raw text?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mentioned... yes it has HTML formatting :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution in jQuery.  A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/6n7dkmrj/) is available.

In the sample, I am splitting at 100 characters so we can see the effect.  The code is as follows:

```
$(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    $("p").each(function (i, element) {
        counter += $(element).text().length;
        if (counter > 100) {
            counter = 0;
            $(element).append("<hr/>");
        }
    });
});
```

The high level of the algorithm is to keep a counter of text sizes for each paragraph and when it exceeds the threshold, add a horizontal line and reset the counter.

Comment: Even better would be to count words

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in PHP

```
$text = "<p>bla...bla</p><p>bla...bla</p><p>bla...bla</p><p>bla...bla</p>"; 
$textArray = explode("</p>",$text);
foreach ($textArray as &$value) {
 echo $value."</p>";
 $countText = strlen(strip_tags($value))+$countText;
  if ($countText > 4999 )
   { echo "<hr/>"; $countText = ""; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to explode it into sentences, then probably select a number maybe 5 sentences in every paragraph and then insert a `<hr>` after every 5 sentences.

To explode text into sentences, you can look at [php sentence boundaries detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032210/php-sentence-boundaries-detection)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(function () {
   var total_length = 0;
   $("p").each(function (i, element) 
   {
       total_length += $(element).text().length;
       if (total_length >= 5000) {
           total_length = 0;
           $(element).append("<hr/>");
        }
   });
 });
```

Hope it will work for you