# PHP sentence boundaries including empty lines?

Tags: php, regex

This is an extension of the [PHP sentences boundaries question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032210/php-sentence-boundaries-detection) on SO.

I'd like know how to change the regex to keep newlines as well.

Sample code to split some text by sentence, remove one sentence, then put back together:

```
<?php
$re = '/# Split sentences on whitespace between them.
    (?<=                # Begin positive lookbehind.
      [.!?]             # Either an end of sentence punct,
    | [.!?][\'"]        # or end of sentence punct and quote.
    )                   # End positive lookbehind.
    (?<!                # Begin negative lookbehind.
      Mr\.              # Skip either "Mr."
    | Mrs\.             # or "Mrs.",
    | Ms\.              # or "Ms.",
    | Jr\.              # or "Jr.",
    | Dr\.              # or "Dr.",
    | Prof\.            # or "Prof.",
    | Sr\.              # or "Sr.",
    | T\.V\.A\.         # or "T.V.A.",
                        # or... (you get the idea).
    )                   # End negative lookbehind.
    [\s+|^$]            # Split on whitespace between sentences/empty lines.
    /ix';

$text = <<<EOL
This is paragraph one. This is sentence one. Sentence two!

This is paragraph two. This is sentence three. Sentence four!
EOL;

echo "\nBefore: \n" . $text . "\n";

$sentences = preg_split($re, $text, -1);

$sentences[1] = " "; // remove 'sentence one'

// put text back together
$text = implode( $sentences );

echo "\nAfter: \n" . $text . "\n";
?>
```

Running this, the output is

```
Before: 
This is paragraph one. This is sentence one. Sentence two!

This is paragraph two. This is sentence three. Sentence four!

After: 
This is paragraph one. Sentence two!
This is paragraph two. This is sentence three. Sentence four!
```

I'm trying to get the 'After' text to be the same as the 'Before' text, just with the one sentence removed.

```
After: 
This is paragraph one. Sentence two!

This is paragraph two. This is sentence three. Sentence four!
```

I'm hoping this can be done with a regex tweak, but what am I missing?

Comment: Looks like there is an issue in this regex: `[\s+|^$]` really matches whitespace, `+`, `|`, `^` and `$` symbols. Replace that with `(?:\h+|^$)` and I guess that is it.

Comment: I think you can just remove the `+` after the `\s` or `\s{1}` if you really need it to match one, because the `\s+` is consuming the other whitespaces.  Essentially you need `array(  "stuf", "\n", "stuff");` but not sure without testing it, and it's too complicated to run in just my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end of the pattern should be replaced with:

```
  (?:\h+|^$)          # Split on whitespace between sentences\/empty lines.
/mix';
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/6syogP)

Note that `[\s+|^$]` really matches whitespace (both horizontal and *vertical*, like newlines), `+`, `|`, `^` and `$` symbols because it is a *character class*.

Instead of a character class, a group (better, non-capturing here) is necessary. Inside a group (marked with `(...)`) the `|` works as an alternation operator.

Instead of `\s`, I suggest using `\h` that matches *horizontal whitespace* (no linebreaks) only.

The `^$` will only match an empty string if no `/m` multiline modifier is used. So, I have added `/m` modifier to the options.

And note that I had to escape the `/` inside the last comment, otherwise there was a warning that the regex is incorrect. Or, use different regex delimiters.

Comment: Thanks. This almost works, with one quirk: the preg_split regex combines two of the sentences together. See http://ideone.com/AUImET  Any idea? Also thanks for \h explanation I wasn't familiar with it.

Comment: What if you add a `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`, use a capturing group with `(\h+|^$)` and zero out the element at Index 2? See [this demo](http://ideone.com/ddq1hV).