# Php splitting a sentence

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to split a string of sentences by "." to get each sentence in an array. Like below:

```
$Text = "Hello, Mr. James. How are you today."
$split= explode(".", $Text);
```

As you can see $Text contains 2 sentences therefore i should only have 2 elements in the array. The issue i'm having is that sometimes my $Text can contain words like "Mr." or any other word which contains a "." in the middle of a sentence. This will result in the sentences being split from the middle and placed separately in the array like below:

```
Array ( [0] => Hello, Mr [1] => James [2] => How are you today [3] => )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Split a text into sentences](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16377437/4577762)

Comment: @FirstOne Almost. The one you're linking relies on whether there's a letter after a dot / space (Mr. James) would register as 2 sentences with that. I think the only way to do this would be check if the first word after a dot is a valid English dictionary word or just a name. Even so it would be very unreliable

Comment: @icecub I didn't flag, just wrote _possible_ ;). Anyways, a google search returned a bunch of results (such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158296/how-to-split-a-paragraph-into-sentences)), but I doubt the op went through all of them.

Comment: @FirstOne Ye I found Natural Language Processing as well. But it's quite a complicated subject. And I wonder how reliable it really is.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/27

Comment: @Peter Close, but it fails on other honorifics like "Miss. James"

Comment: I think the easiest solution would simply be `/(?<! Mr| Mrs)\./i` and expending the list with all honorifics.

Comment: Yes, there isn't perfect solution. There is the closest solution WITH tons of exceptions :)

Comment: @Peter Exactly. There's no perfect solution for this problem. Hence I'm not turning this into an answer, haha

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid a lot of exception handling and general misery, if you can ensure that all English sentences are **properly** spaced at the end of each sentence -- 2 consecutive spaces.  This can be difficult when dealing with some digitized strings because sometimes multi-spacing gets condensed to a single space.

This is what I mean:

```
$Text = "Hello, Mr. James.  How are you today.";
$split = explode("  ", $Text);
var_export($split);
// array ( 0 => 'Hello, Mr. James.', 1 => 'How are you today.', )
```

Exploding on each `space-space` will give you a reliable result.
If you want *good* output, you'll need to use *good* input.

---

If you want to blacklist a few predictable substrings that should not be use to split the string, then you can use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` for that.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ltvli))

```
$text = "Hello, Mr. James. How are you today.";

var_export(
    preg_split('~(?:Mrs?|Miss|Ms|Prof|Rev|Col|Dr)[.?!:](*SKIP)(*F)|[.?!:]+\K\s+~', $text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Hello, Mr. James.',
  1 => 'How are you today.',
)
```